# How to delete the row in a dataframe panda based on the row names of another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, metadata

I want to short my data, the whole data shape is 30000x480. And I want to drop some rows based on the row names of another data frame.

Help me to solve it and get the solution for:

> df1

```
Row  a  b
A    1  2
B    3  4
C    5  6
D    7  8
E    9 10
F   11 12
G   13 14
```

> df2

```
Row  a  b
C    5  6
D    7  8
F   11 12
G   13 14
```

So, I want to delete the rows in df1 that doesn't exist on the df2, it's hard to delete as manually because the data is very big

Comment: try `df1.merge(df2)`

Comment: What have you tried?https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/2327328

Comment: @vb_rises It's can't work because the number of df1 columns is not the same as the number of df2 columns

Comment: @philshem It still doesn't work

Comment: @mayasari you just want to delete on the column 'ROW'? what is desired output in above case?

Comment: @vb_rises Well, the shape and the column values both of the data frames were different.  Shape of df1 is 30981 rows and 483 columns, while shape of df2 is 8094 rows and 164 columns. I want to delete the rows of df1 base on the row names of df2, so the output of this case is the data of df1 values with the shape to be 8094 x 483

Comment: Can we narrow this down to use the Row column? Or does the entire row need to be the same?

Answer (score 0):

For better understanding, taking the same data given. Let me put the same question in a different context for a better understanding as below:

Question : Want to delete the rows in df1 that doesn't exist on the df2

New way : you need the rows of df1 that are present in df2 (or) in a way you need the common rows of both df1 & df2, try this

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Row': ['C', 'D', 'F','G'], 'a': [5, 7, 11, 13], 'b' : [6, 8, 12, 14]})
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Row' : ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], 'a': [1,3,5,7], 'b': [2,4,6, 8]})
>>> df1
  Row  a  b
0   A  1  2
1   B  3  4
2   C  5  6
3   D  7  8
>>> df2
  Row   a   b
0   C   5   6
1   D   7   8
2   F  11  12
3   G  13  14
>>> pd.merge(df1, df2, 'inner')
  Row  a  b
0   C  5  6
1   D  7  8
>>>
```